# List generated from For loop with .append() of another JSON data

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, for-loop

```
myjson = [
    {"GROUP" : "A",
    "TYPE" : "I",
    "VALUE1" : 25,
    "VALUE2" : 26,
    "REMARK" : "None"},

    {"GROUP" : "B",
    "TYPE" : "II",
    "VALUE1" : 33,
    "VALUE2" : 22,
    "REMARK" : "None"}
]
```

Expected output

```
[{'GROUP': 'A', 'TYPE': 'I'}, {'GROUP': 'B', 'TYPE': 'II'}]
```

My approach

For each item in `myjson`, selecting keys `GROUP` and `TYPE` to form a dictionary object, and append these two dictionaries object into another list `myjson2`

```
temp = {}
myjson2 = []

for listitem in myjson:
    for key, item in listitem.items():
        if key == "GROUP" or key == "TYPE":          
            temp[key] = item
    print(temp)
    myjson2.append(temp)
```

The `print(temp)` above gives:

```
{'GROUP': 'A', 'TYPE': 'I'}
{'GROUP': 'B', 'TYPE': 'II'}
```

I wonder why the following results after each `.append()`.

```
print(myjson2)
[{'GROUP': 'B', 'TYPE': 'II'}, {'GROUP': 'B', 'TYPE': 'II'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why not working:** You need to append the new dictionary every time instead of overwriting the old one with a new value. Just move that temp inside the first `for`,

```
 myjson = [
  {
    "GROUP": "A",
    "TYPE": "I",
    "VALUE1": 25,
    "VALUE2": 26,
    "REMARK": "None"
  },
  {
    "GROUP": "B",
    "TYPE": "II",
    "VALUE1": 33,
    "VALUE2": 22,
    "REMARK": "None"
  }
]
myjson2 = []
for listitem in myjson:
    temp = {}
    for key, item in listitem.items():
        if key == "GROUP" or key == "TYPE":          
            temp[key] = item
    myjson2.append(temp)
print(myjson2)
```

**One-Liner:** with list comprehension

`myjson2 = [{key:val for key, val in dic.items() if key in ['GROUP', 'TYPE']} for dic in myjson]`

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is caused by `temp` being defined once outside the loops.

Move the definition inside the first `for` so we clear it for each item in the list:

```py
myjson2 = []

for listitem in myjson:
    temp = {}
    for key, item in listitem.items():
        if key == "GROUP" or key == "TYPE":    
      
            temp[key] = item
    print(temp)
    myjson2.append(temp)

print(myjson2)
```

```json
{'GROUP': 'A', 'TYPE': 'I'}
{'GROUP': 'B', 'TYPE': 'II'}
[{'GROUP': 'A', 'TYPE': 'I'}, {'GROUP': 'B', 'TYPE': 'II'}]
```

---

###### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY9LC8IwEITv@RVLThaKYIseCj1UKCI@KSqIeBCsGB9psL0U8bfX7CYRoZpDYL@Z3WFUXZ0LGTbNvb6UhYQYdgz0e/JRtlgvOUTAE@4T46vtMiUydmSTTNdpD1nQ/0YBoYFFWTpLsgltzguZ85fPWiHDdsiPlDBspwT/UtieMWZ6BVhMj6fiATdRVqLK7yAkGDWiAxopbXu@aELnNa99cFa31sWv7HhmCZ84oRPiGFwfs0uE6kRos/7PmsvcaeteB@NdEtVDyKqDkkezrdA9KJXLoxWYcVnNa5o3)

Answer (score 1):

It's because `temp` keep reference to the same dictionary object and what you did in inside `for key, item in listitem.items()` is essentially change the value of the dictionary and since the last value of the `listitem` is `{'GROUP': 'B', 'TYPE': 'II'}`, `temp` will in the end has these keys-values. You can simply fix this by reference `temp` to a new object in every new iteration

```
for listitem in myjson:
    temp = {}
    for key, item in listitem.items():
        if key == "GROUP" or key == "TYPE":          
            temp[key] = item
    print(temp)
    myjson2.append(temp)
```